# BroadCast Receiver makes slowly works to other services

Tags: android, push-notification

when I listen push message from BroadcastReceiver I can take message but it makes slow other services for example I am sending "Message is taken" to my web service when I take push message but I can't send to my webservice it works very slowly when I listen to BroadcastReceiver for take message and when I delete BroadcastReceiver I can send message to my webservice very fastly

```
package jsonparse;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MapsActivity;
import com.androidhive.pushnotifications.R;
import com.androidhive.pushnotifications.ServerUtilities;
import com.androidhive.pushnotifications.WakeLocker;
import com.daasuu.ahp.AnimateHorizontalProgressBar;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION;
import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;


public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //ProgressBar mprogressBar;
    TextView fulness;
    TextView location_info;
    TextView descrip;
    JSONObject jsonobject;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private int mProgressStatus=0;

    String get_enlem,get_boylam;
    double dble_get_enlem,dble_get_boylam;
    String dest_city_name,dest_state_name,dest_country_name;

    NetworkInfo ni;
    ConnectivityManager cm;
    String get_location;
    String device_id;
    String sonuc;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    String get_groupID, get_customerID;

    String get_desc;

    String get_toplam;

    // Asyntask
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;
    public static String name;
    public static String email;

    Context con;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        /*
          TextView rank;
          TextView country;
          TextView population;
          ImageView flag;
        */
        TextView location;
        AnimateHorizontalProgressBar progressBar;
        Button cop_toplandi;



        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);



        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        //rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        //country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        //population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);

        //Get Device IMEI number
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        device_id = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        Log.i("IMEI NUMBER", device_id);


        // Getting name, email from intent
        Intent i = ((Activity) context).getIntent();

        name = i.getStringExtra("get_message_name");
        email = i.getStringExtra("email");



        Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
                GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);

                // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
                // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
                GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);

                context.registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                        DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));


                // Get GCM registration id
                final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);

                // Check if regid already presents
                if (regId.equals("")) {
                    // Registration is not present, register now with GCM
                    GCMRegistrar.register(context, SENDER_ID);
                } else {
                    // Device is already registered on GCM
                    if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
                        // Skips registration.
                        //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                        // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                        // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                        final Context contextm = context;
                        mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                // Register on our server
                                // On server creates a new user
                                ServerUtilities.register(contextm, name, email, regId);
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                                mRegisterTask = null;
                            }

                        };
                        mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);





        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("login_page", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        get_groupID = prefs.getString("user_groupID", "alınmadı");
        get_customerID = prefs.getString("user_customerID", "alınmadı");

        if (get_groupID.equals("null")) {

            get_groupID = "0";
        }

        if (get_customerID.equals("null")) {

            get_customerID = "0";
        }

        location =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        progressBar = (AnimateHorizontalProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.animate_progress_bar);
        fulness = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_percentage_of_fulness);
        descrip = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);

        get_location = resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY);
        cop_toplandi = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.secret_button);
        cop_toplandi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Başarıyla Gönderildi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new Send_save_status().execute();

            }
        });
        location_info = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_info);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        //flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        //rank.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
        //country.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
        //population.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
        location.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
        location_info.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.Location_info));


        String get_descrip = resultp.get(MainActivity.DESCB);
        if(get_descrip != "0"){

            descrip.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.DESCB));
            cop_toplandi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        get_enlem = resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION);
        get_boylam = resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG);

        get_toplam = resultp.get(MainActivity.Toplam);

        //dble_get_enlem = Double.parseDouble(get_enlem);
        //dble_get_boylam = Double.parseDouble(get_boylam);

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG), flag);
        // Capture ListView item click
        String a =  resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(a);

        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(b);



        //progressBar.setProgressWithAnim(b);
        fulness.setText("%"+(b*1));
        //mprogressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        //mprogressBar.setProgress(b);
/*
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mprogressBar, "progress", 0, 80);
        anim.setDuration(5000);
        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.start();
*/

/*
        //Get location name from latitude and longitude
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(dble_get_enlem, dble_get_boylam, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dest_city_name = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        dest_state_name = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        dest_country_name = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

        location_info.setText(dest_city_name + " " + dest_country_name);
*/

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()) {


                    Toast.makeText(context,context.getString(R.string.progressdialog_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Get the position
                    resultp = data.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                    // Pass all data rank
                    intent.putExtra("level", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
                    // Pass all data country
                    intent.putExtra("imei", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
                    // Pass all data population
                    intent.putExtra("enlem",resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
                    // Pass all data flag
                    intent.putExtra("boylam", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
                    // Start SingleItemView Class
                    context.startActivity(intent);


                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),context.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.network_connection),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){



        }
    }


    /**
     * Receiving push messages
     * */

    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(context);

            //context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT"));
            //context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT"));



            // Showing received message
            //lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            //descrip.setText(newMessage);

            // Intent go = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),IsEmri.class);
            //context.startActivity(go);


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            builder.setTitle("Acil Durum!!!");

            builder.setMessage(newMessage)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // TODO: handle the OK
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();



            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();


        }
    };



    /*
   Send GroupID and customerID every five minutes to services
*/
    private class Send_save_status extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {




            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.gprs_adres) + address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // make sure you close the gps after using it. Save user's battery power
            //mGPSService.closeGPS();



            StringBuilder str_url = new StringBuilder();
            str_url.append("http://78.186.62.169:8090/TrackBinSvc.svc/saveStatus/");
            Log.i("str_url1", "" + str_url);
            str_url.append(device_id + "/");
            Log.i("strl_url2", "" + str_url);
            str_url.append(get_location + "/");
            Log.i("strl_url3", "" + str_url);
            str_url.append("opened" + "/");
            Log.i("strl_url3", "" + str_url);
            str_url.append(get_groupID + "/");
            Log.i("strl_url3", "" + str_url);
            str_url.append(get_customerID);
            Log.i("strl_url3", "" + str_url);

            String str = str_url.toString();


//"http://192.168.0.39:8090/TrackBinSvc.svc/Get_All_Mobile/admin/1234"
            try {
                jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                        .getJSONfromURL(str);
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                sonuc = jsonobject.getString("SendUpdateCordinatesResult");


            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is: The broadcast receiver that you are registering is implemented on the Main thread. The broadcast receiver handler is ALWAYS EXECUTED ON THE MAIN THREAD, thus, making your entire process slower. To implement receiver's own thread, you can explicitly do so by providing it's own Handler thread.

Register your broadcast receiver like this:

```
HandlerThread receiverHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("threadName");
receiverHandlerThread.start();
Looper looper = receiverHandlerThread.getLooper();
Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
context.registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,newIntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION),null,handler);
```

Comment: hi,I was do all register process in Handler but I get a same error it works slowly,I was update my code,you can see up.